# Upload filestream to cloud-files with Node.js

Tags: node.js, upload, filestream, express, rackspace-cloud

I know that it's possible to upload files to my cloud-files account in Node.js, using the following module: [node-cloudfiles](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-cloudfiles). 
But is it also possible to upload a filestream directly? 
In my case I am dowloading an image from a certain location in Node.js and want to upload this directly to my cloud-files account without saving the image temporary on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible - you can just read the documentation on Rackspace Cloud Files API ( http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/files/api/cf-devguide-latest.pdf ) and implement the necessary parts yourself.

However, I'd suggest to wait until https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-cloudfiles/pull/11 gets integrated into the trunk - then node-cloudfiles library will support uploading files using streams so you won't have to create files before uploading.

Comment: I think i'll go for your suggestion and wait till the pull request gets integrated. Maybe I can use the [request](https://github.com/rocketpack/node-cloudfiles) as a temporary solution.